# the best way for throwing and managing exception java - spring?

Tags: java, spring, exception, runtimeexception

I want to ask if someone can help me that what is the best way for managing exception like if we add some user and want to throw for ex. UserNotExist should we extend with Exception or Runtime exception , does anyone have any material that can help me .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

Answer (score 0):

As exceptions inherited from `Exception` class are **checked** exceptions, and exceptions inherited from `RuntimeException` class are **unchecked** exceptions, your question may be viewed, as what kind of exceptions to use.

As recommended in Oracle [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html):

> If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception.
>   If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.